# Escrever para um listBox noutro form

Tags: c#, winforms

Boas stack.

Estou a desenvolver uma pequena aplicação para backup automático de Bases de Dados MySQL e SQL Server. A aplicação esta a ser feita em Windows Forms + C#.

Pensei implementar algo parecido com uma "consola", sendo na verdade uma listBox que vai guardar os logs. A minha ideia era conseguir guardar os logs dentro dessa listBox. Por exemplo:

```
14:22:34 - Vou começar a backup a base de dados: user_control
14:23:10 - Terminei o backup de: user_control C:/backups
```

Agora sobre a questão. Como é que eu posso enviar conteúdo de classes para essa listBox? Tenho múltiplas classes e múltiplas formas, mas envio sempre para um unico local.

Tentei criar uma função publica no mesmo form da listBox e enviar para lá argumentos. A função iria pegar nele e pôr na listBox. Mas não sei chamar pela função sem criar uma nova instância.

A tal função. Esta em `Form1.cs`

```
public void addLog(string content) {
        ConsoleLog.Items.Add(content);
    }
```

Um exemplo do que tenho tentado fazer. Esta em frmAdicionar.cs

```
addLog("Olá mundo");
```

Não sei se me expliquei com toda a clareza, estou disposto a partilhar mais iformações.

Comment: Isso depende de como  seu projeto está estruturado, namespaces, etc... mas  a principio, criaria uma `Queue<string>` estática, nas classes iria colocando o texto na `Queue`, e no form, tiraria e colocaria no controle...Há ainda a opção de criar eventos nas classes, e captura-los no form... um pouco mais avançado...

Comment: Rovann, obrigado pela ideia. Dei uma vista de olhos nas Queue e rapidamente apercebi-me que pode ser uma solução. Não consegui encontrar, neste meros momentos, uma solução para tirar o texto a não ser ticks do timer. Todos os segundos ele vai lá e vê se tem alguma coisa para exportar. Obrigado mais uma vez pela sugestão dos Queue, não conhecia que isso existia. As melhores :D